# @fastify/cors issue giving me preflight 404

Tags: cors, fastify

I have a very simple backend running with Fastify. This is my code:

```js
export class HttpServer {

    async start() {
        try {
            const fastify = Fastify();
            await fastify.register(cors);
            fastify.post('/auth/login', loginRoute);
            fastify.post('/auth/refresh', refreshRoute);
            fastify.get('/user/current', { preHandler: authMiddleware }, getCurrentUser);
            await fastify.listen({ port: 4001, host: "0.0.0.0" });
            console.log(` [HttpServer]: Successfully started!`);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(` [HttpServer]: Not possible to start!`);
            process.exit(1);
        }
    }

}
```

on my entry point, I just do:

```js
await httpServer.start();
```

The thing is that, I can make the requests properly from Insomnia for example, it works. But whenever I try to make a request from my client, it gives me the CORS error saying:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:4001/auth/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I honestly already tried multiple options to the cors when registering it to the fastify instance, even tried to manually apply the cors, but nothing seems to be working. Regarding my front-end, I don't see any issue at all.. this is my code:

```js
import axios from "axios";

export function getAPI() {

    const api = axios.create({
        baseURL: 'http://localhost:4001'
    })

    return api;
}
```

then I do:

```js
const api = getAPI()
await api.post('/auth/login', {
  token
})
...
```

Can someone please help me figure out what's happening here? Thanks.

Obs: I did a test using express and the "cors" package, it worked fine. So I assume it's a problem with fastify or @fastify/cors.

Comment: Did you try to set the `origin` config of the cors plugin to '*' already?